# How do I get more henchmen?

Tags: evil-genius

In Evil Genius, how do I go about getting more henchmen to accomplish my evil deeds? Lord Kane is great and all, but one pair of hands can only get so much evil done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At certain levels of Infamy, you'll gain the ability to recruit new Henchmen.  The amount of infamy needed varies depending on the henchman you wish to recruit.  You can have a max of three, so you'll want to consider carefully which other two to pick up.  Of course, if one of your Henchmen dies, you can replace him or her.  (They can only permanently die if killed repeatedly by one of the Super Agents)

Continue doing Acts of Infamy on the world map, and you'll soon see Henchmen recruitment missions popping up.  There's a list of the henchmen, their skills, and the requirements to recruit them [here](http://wiki.n1nj4.com/index.php?title=Henchmen).  When I cleared the game, my team was Eli, Jubei, and The Matron.